# If $G$ is cyclic of order $2$ show $|H^1(G,\mathbb{Z})|=2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $2$ acting by inversion on $\mathbb{Z}$. Show $|H^1(G,\mathbb{Z})|=2$. A hint is provided: if $E=\mathbb{Z} \rtimes G$ then every element in $E - \mathbb{Z}$ has order $2$ and there are two conjugacy classes.

To solve this its clearly enough to classify the splittings of the exact sequence $\mathbb{Z} \to E \to G$ up to $G$-conjugacy. I've shown the first part of the hint but I'm not sure how to do the second part. Also, with that, how do I get the splittings? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You can use a resolution of $\Bbb Z$ as a $\Bbb Z C_2$ module, namely a $2$-periodic resolution using $1-\sigma$ and $1+\sigma$ with $\sigma$ the generator of $C_2$. This should help you compute both homology and cohomology easily.

Comment: The group $E$ is the infinite dihedral group, which has two conjugacy classes of elements of order $2$.